# "Transform" Numpy Arrray: Move Dimension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm creating array a:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3, 10, 10), np.uint8)
a[1,5,5] = 255
```

with a red dot in the center, where the RGB is the first dimension. Then I plot it using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(a)
```

But of course this doesn't work because imshow expects an array with dimensions (10, 10, 3) and I am feeding it an array with dimensions (3, 10, 10). How could I 'flip' the array so that the RGB is the third dimension, instead of the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `swapaxes`.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3, 10, 10), np.uint8)

print(a.shape) #(3,10,10)

print(np.swapaxes(a,0,2).shape) #(10,10,3)
```

See [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html).

---

`np.swapaxes(a,0,2)` equals to `np.transpose(a, (2,1,0))`.

There is another option which is `np.transpose(a, (1,2 0))`.

As always, transpose matrix can have two versions which produce similar result but with different 3-dimensional rotational symmetry.

It depends on if the mirror matrix affect your result, you should carefully test if it makes difference.

Comment: `np.transpose(a, (1,2 0))` is another option.  Your swap is equal to `np.transpose(a, (2,1,0))`, which transposes the (10,10) part.  That may, or might not, be what the OP wants.

Comment: @hpaulj , oops, you are right. There should be another option such that the two result are mirror matrix. I will make an adjustment.

Comment: You can use `np.moveaxis(a, 0, 2)` which is slightly more readable---but slower---than `np.transpose(a, (1, 2, 0))`

Comment: I make this community post. As it seems like it no longer just the work of mine.