# How to transpose 3D matrix like 2D?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to transpose 3D matrix but without touching most inner list. The 3D matrix is numpy array of an image and the goal of transposition is to rotate image but not to change pixel values(r.g.b).

```
image = np.array(
    [
        [[15, 15, 25], [50, 50, 50], [90, 90, 90], [255, 255, 255], [127, 127, 127]],

        [[121, 121, 121], [75, 10, 75], [187, 187, 187], [0, 0, 0], [210, 50, 100]],

        [[31, 31, 31], [63, 63, 63], [87, 87, 87], [63, 63, 63], [63, 63, 63]],

        [[95, 95, 95], [95, 95, 95], [115, 115, 115], [87, 87, 87], [95, 95, 95]],

        [[95, 95, 95], [63, 63, 63], [63, 63, 63], [87, 87, 87], [100, 250, 250]]
    ], dtype=np.uint8)
```

The result should be something like this.

```
result = np.array(
    [
        [[15, 15, 25], [121, 121, 121], [31, 31, 31], [95, 95, 95], [95, 95, 95]],

        [[50, 50, 50], [75, 10, 75], [63, 63, 63], [95, 95, 95], [63, 63, 63]],

        [[90, 90, 90], [187, 187, 187], [87, 87, 87], [115, 115, 115], [63, 63, 63]],

        [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [63, 63, 63], [87, 87, 87], [87, 87, 87]],

        [[127, 127, 127], [210, 50, 100], [63, 63, 63], [95, 95, 95], [100, 250, 250]]
    ], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: `image.transpose(1,0,2)` should do the trick.  Without the argument `transpose` is like `(2,1,0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to [np.swapaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html)

```
np.swapaxes(image, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52360048/transform-numpy-arrray-move-dimension)

basically use this

```
numpy.swapaxes(image,0,1)
```